# I am not able to build a sample file using XLNT library

Tags: c++, build, linker-errors

I am trying to build a simple C++ program with xlnt with GNU compiler and Visual Studio Code IDE.  I have had some challenges with getting the build environment to include the xlnt libraries, and the problem may be related to that.  The program is below:

```
#include <xlnt/xlnt.hpp>

int main() {
    // Create a new workbook and load an existing file
    xlnt::workbook wb;            // <---- this is line 6, which is causing the error (below)
    try {
        wb.load("example.xlsx");
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Error loading file: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the following output (partial):

> [build] [ 50%] Building CXX object
> CMakeFiles/ExcelAccess.dir/src/ExcelAccess.cpp.obj
>
> [build] [100%] Linking CXX executable ExcelAccess.exe
>
> [build]
> C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
> CMakeFiles\ExcelAccess.dir/objects.a(ExcelAccess.cpp.obj): in function
> `main':
>
> [build]
> C:/Users/Public/Documents/Excel/src/ExcelAccess.cpp:6:(.text+0x19):
> undefined reference to `xlnt::workbook::workbook()'
>
> [build]
> C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
> C:/Users/Public/Documents/Excel/src/ExcelAccess.cpp:8:(.text+0x4d):
> undefined reference to
> `xlnt::workbook::load(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,
> std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&)'

Any ideas how to resolve the error: undefined reference to `xlnt::workbook::workbook()'?

xlnt previously built, with the following output:

[main] Building folder: xlnt

[build] Starting build

[proc] Executing command: chcp

[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --
build c:/xlnt/xlnt/build --config Debug --target all -j 42 --

[build] [ 11%] Built target libstudxml

[build] [100%] Built target xlnt

[driver] Build completed: 00:00:00.909

[build] Build finished with exit code 0

Comment: the error happens at link time, so i guess you do not link against XNLT library. What is your command to compile the program?

Comment: I am building within Visual Studio Code, and F7 build.  Tasks.json includes: args "-I/C:/xlnt/xlnt/include/**", which is the location of the xlnt include folder.

Comment: try adding -lxlnt -L/path/to/xlnt/lib to your args. -lname i to link with library named name and -Lpath is to tell the compiler where to look for libraries if they are not at default locations

Comment: I do not see a xlnt/lib folder, so the issue might be the xlnt build.  I added information above in the issue description about the xlnt build.